# position of span text inside parent div

Tags: html, css

I am working on a CSS issue. I have a parent div and there are some child spans in it which getting generated dynamically as block element...

I need to have the text of span in the right hand side of div but if the text is more than parent div then it should not be wrapped to right align. it should be align left..

I used text-align:right.. but the first text in my span wrapping to right which i dont want. I tried float - right, position - fixed etc.. but couldnt fix it.

Here is my code ..

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.spanLabel {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2.2em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="spanLabel">
 ExcellentExcellentAAExcellentExcellentAAExcellentE
  </span>
  <span class="spanLabel">
 Good
  </span>
</div>
```

I need something like the text of span should be right side of parent div but if text grows then next line should be left align.. I need to have same css for span as it is getting generated dynamically in a loop..

Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: CSS can't *detect* that.. You'd need Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Bassicaly, with CSS you can't do it. With jQuery it's not a problem. Take a look to this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divheight = $(".spanLabel").height();
    var lineheight = $(".spanLabel").css('line-height').replace("px","");
    alert(Math.round(divheight/parseInt(lineheight)));
});
```

Here we count how many lines your `span` have. Then, if 
`Math.round(divheight/parseInt(lineheight))`

more than 1, you can alight your text to left:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divheight = $(".spanLabel").height();
    var lineheight = $(".spanLabel").css('line-height').replace("px","");
    if (Math.round(divheight/parseInt(lineheight)) > 1) {
        $(".spanLabel").css('text-align', 'left');
    }
});
```

Also, take a look how I understand how many lines in `span`. I take value of `line-height`. If you can't setup it, value will be a `normal`. Than will be an error in script. In this always points `line-height`. Standard value: 16px, in most of browsers.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyeg1gkm) is demo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divheight = $(".spanLabel").height();
    var lineheight = $(".spanLabel").css('line-height').replace("px","");
    if (Math.round(divheight/parseInt(lineheight)) > 1) {
     $(".spanLabel").css('text-align', 'left');
    }
});
```

```css
.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    width:20%; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right:15px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.spanLabel {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom: 2.2em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align:right;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span class="spanLabel">
        ExcellentExcellentAAExcellentExcellentAAExcellentE
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float: right`. It will align the elements to the right, and the text inside them to their left.

Since, for floated elements, auto widths are calculated using the [shrink-to-fit algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float),

- If the text occupies less space than the available in the wrapper, the floated element will be as wide as the text, so it will look like the text is aligned to the right.
- If the text is wider than the wrapper, the floated element will be as wide as the wrapper. The text will be wrapped into multiple lines, aligned to the left.

  Note an exception will be that, if there are no break opportunities in the text, the floated element might grow bigger than the wrapper. To avoid this, you can use one of these:

  - `max-width: 100%`
  - `word-break: break-all`
  - Add breaking opportunities in the HTML, e.g. spaces or `&shy;`

However, if the floated elements are narrow enough, they will be positioned one adjacent to another. To prevent this, you can use [clearance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#flow-control).

So the final code would be something like

```css
.spanLabel {
  float: right;    /* Align to the right */
  clear: right;    /* Prevent adjacency */
  max-width: 100%; /* Just in case the text has no break opportunities */
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.spanLabel {
  margin-bottom: 2.2em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="spanLabel">
    ExcellentExcellentAAExcellentExcellentAAExcellentE
  </span>
  <span class="spanLabel">
    Good
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply .. but if the text in first span is less 100% then it is problem. for e.g having only "Excellent" in first span making Good and Excellent in one line ..:(

Comment: @Lalit_Test You are right of course, I forgot `clear: right`